# How to catch custom error raised in method of object?

Tags: laravel, laravel-exceptions

On laravel 9 site in my custom class method raise custom error with error message

```
<?php

    class CustomClass
    {
    
        use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
        use Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\HttpResponseException;
        ...
        public function method(): array
        {
    
        if(false) {
            throw new HttpResponseException(response()->json([
                'message' => $validated['message'],
            ], 422));
        }
```

but I failed to catch this error in control where methods raised :

```
{
    try {
        $imageUploadSuccess = $customClass->method(
            ...
        ); // This method can raise different types of exception
    }
    catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) { // exception with invalid id is catched - THIS PART WORKS OK 
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Item  not found',
        ], 404);
    }
    catch (HttpResponseException $e) { //  I catch HttpResponseException with is generated in method
        // None of these 2 methods returns custom error message in method :
        \Log::info($e->getMessage()); // empty value - I NEED TO GET THIS MESSAGE TEXT
        \Log::info($e->getCode());    // 0 value
        \Log::info($e->getTraceAsString());
        return response()->json([
            'message' => $e->getMessage(),
        ], 422);
    }
    return response()->json(['success' => true],  400);
```

Have I to use other class, not HttpResponseException ? I which way ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re not throwing your custom exception so it’s never raised so it won’t be catchable.

Replace where you throw the `HttpResponseException` with your Exception.

```
<?php

class CustomClass
{
    public function method()
    {
        $isValid = false;
        if(!$isValid) {
            throw new SomeCustomException(response()->json([
                'message' => $validated['message'],
            ], 422));
        }
    }
}
```

You would then use do something like:

```
$customClass = new CustomClass();
$customClass->method();
```

Note how I have defined a variable `$isValid` and how I check it for a `true` or `false` value in the `if` statement. This is because `if` checks for `truthy` values and `false` will never be `true so your custom exception would never be thrown.

```
if (false) {
    // code in here will never execute
}
```

Comment: Do you mean " with your Exception"  to create custom exception ?

Comment: @PetroGromovo I have literally shown you what I mean

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand you. I show piece of code with ModelNotFoundException - to catch error of invalid item id. But I need to get custom data inside of  catch (HttpResponseException $e) {...

Comment: @PetroGromovo I have updated my answer to provide more clarity.

Comment: What is in your responce ModelNotFoundException ? Custom exception? Actually ModelNotFoundException is laravel standart exception. I put it into my code to show that there several exceptions for method calling. I tried to use HttpResponseException(I found ref to it in the net...).  Sorry, if I pure put my question.

Comment: @PetroGromovo Can you update your question please to provide your actual custom exception and how/where you intend to use it. It appears you have omitted crucial information from your question which is making answering it more complicated.

Comment: @PetroGromovo Do you actually have a custom exception, or do you just mean you want to customise the message of `HttpResponseException`?

Comment: 1) I  tried to use HttpResponseException (I found ref to it in net), but failed with error message. 2) Maybe I have to create a custom exception and use it? In which way ?

Comment: @PetroGromovo You're not answering the question I have asked. What are you trying to do? Are you trying to use a custom exception, or are you trying to customise the `HttpResponseException` message?

Comment: I try with raised exception in method to pass error message to controller from where method is called. I tried to customise and use HttpResponseException. I do not know which way is valid...

Comment: @PetroGromovo OK, so if you're code is **EXACTLY** as it is in your question the problem is your `if(false)` statement. I have already explained what is wrong with this in my answer.